# Can't scroll result pane in Google Maps

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scroll the result pane on the left side of the window in Google Maps, but this code I used is not scrolling the result pane and it's not showing any errors.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

url = "https://www.google.com/maps/@12.959744,77.6142848,12z?entry=ttu"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(15)
# find text_field and search for restaurants
search_box = WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@id = 'searchboxinput']")))
time.sleep(5)
search_box.send_keys("restaurants")
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(12)
# scroll the result pane
results = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@role="feed"]')))
time.sleep(10)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
time.sleep(8)
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have provided seems correct, but it is possible that the result pane may not have loaded completely when you attempted to scroll it. You can try increasing the wait time for the presence of the result pane element and see if that helps.

Additionally, you could also try scrolling the result pane using the ActionChains class from the selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains module.This code moves the mouse cursor to the result pane, clicks it to give it focus, and then sends a PAGE_DOWN key press to simulate scrolling down. You may need to adjust the wait time and number of PAGE_DOWN key presses based on your specific use case.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    
results = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@role="feed"]')))
time.sleep(10)    
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(results).click().perform()
action.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()
```

Comment: used PAGE DOWN key instead scroll, now its working fine